# Supported Screen manifest android Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Google play not 'view' tag supported screen in android manifest made at the Corona SDK build 840. Google 'says' that the application is designed for screens of small-xlarge, although in the build.settings is written to support only small and normal size.

build.settings file:

```
settings =
{
   android =
   {
      supportsScreens =
      {
         resizeable = false,
         smallScreens = true,
         normalScreens = true,
         largeScreens = false,
         xlargeScreens = false,
      }
   },

   iphone =
    {
        plist =
        {
            UIAppFonts = 
            {
                "Mail Ray Stuff.ttf"
            },
        CFBundleIconFile = "Icon.png",
        CFBundleIconFiles = {
               "Icon.png", 
               "Icon@2x.png", 
               "Icon-72.png", 
            },  
        },
    },  
}
```

decoded AndroidManifest.xml

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:resizeable="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="false"
    >
</supports-screens>
```

but when loaded into Google play wrote, which supports all sizes

http://clip2net.com/s/281fT

what am I doing wrong?